# Change static folder from config in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Has anyone tried this snippet [flask config based static folder code cnippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/102/)?

The code:

```
import flask
class MyFlask(flask.Flask):
    @property
    def static_folder(self):
        if self.config.get('STATIC_FOLDER') is not None:
            return os.path.join(self.root_path, 
                self.config.get('STATIC_FOLDER'))
    @static_folder.setter
    def static_folder(self, value):
        self.config.get('STATIC_FOLDER') = value

# Now these are equivalent:
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='foo')

app = MyFlask(__name__)
app.config['STATIC_FOLDER'] = 'foo'
```

In my case in complains about this line:

```
self.config.get('STATIC_FOLDER') = value
```

The error message: `Can't assign to function call`

Does anyone how to set the static_folder from the config.py file in Flask?

Comment: 404 http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/102/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know anything about that snippet, but

```
some_function(...) = some_value
```

is never valid Python (Python doesn't have [l-values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3601602/857390)). It looks like `config` has a dict-like interface, so the offending line should probably just be

```
self.config['STATIC_FOLDER'] = value
```

Probably a copy-and-paste error from the getter definition above the setter.

Answer (score 16):

Okay, I assume you want to use a custom path to the static folder for whatever reason. I wanted to do the same for the sake of better app modularity.

Here's my app folder structure:

```
instance/
core/
  |_templates/
  |_static/
  |_views.py
run.py
config.py
```

As you can see, my `static` folder is inside the `core` folder.

In `run.py`, you can do the following:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path=None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config.from_object('config')

    # config file has STATIC_FOLDER='/core/static'
    app.static_url_path=app.config.get('STATIC_FOLDER')

    # set the absolute path to the static folder
    app.static_folder=app.root_path + app.static_url_path

    print(app.static_url_path)
    print(app.static_folder)

    app.run(
        host=app.config.get('HOST'),
        port=app.config.get('PORT'),
        threaded=True
        )
```

This is what I did, and it works perfectly fine. I'm using flask 0.12.

Comment: app_ = Flask(__name__, static_url_path=None)
app_.config.from_object('config')
# i fix the bug with down there code .thank you a lot.
app_.static_folder = app_.config.get("STATICFILES_DIR")
app_.template_folder = app_.config.get("TEMPLATES_DIR")

Answer (score 8):

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/STATIC_FOLDER", static_folder='STATIC_FOLDER')
```

Comment: Can you explain which what is the difference between  static_url_path, static_folder?

Comment: @YasinFarmani see also the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/45623197/735926

Comment: The question specifically asks about setting the static folder via the Flask config structure as opposed to this line, which sets in in the app creation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, In one of my projects I am using/setting a custom path for `STATIC_FOLDER`. You can set the path to `STATIC_FOLDER` in `config.py` like below:

```
STATIC_PATH = '<project-name>/<path-to-static-folder>/'
```

ex:

```
STATIC_PATH = 'myApp/static/'
```

If you can write your project structure then I can answer it as per your requirements.

Comment: So, is it STATIC_FOLDER or STATIC_PATH?

Answer (score 0):

FYI if you want your directory to be outside of the server directory the best solutions I found so far are either to make a copy of your directory into the server directory before startup in your main(), or to create a symlink.