# Unable to understand how flask uses url_for

Tags: html, css, flask, bootstrap-4

I have a very simple use case. I have downloaded the flask clean blog files from the link : https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/clean-blog/ and my intention is to build a blog website.

For starters i am just trying to load the index page using a very simple script :

Test.py :

```
from flask import Flask,render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have the below module structure :

```
C:.
│   Test.py
│
├───static
│   └───css
│           bootstrap.min.css
│           clean-blog.min.css
│           font-awesome.min.css
│
└───templates
        index.html
```

Now my index.html file is as follows :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Clean Blog - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" >

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/font-awesome.min.css') }}"  >
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic'  type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/clean-blog.min.css') }}" >

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          Menu
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="post.html">Sample Post</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Header -->
    <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('img/home-bg.jpg')">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <div class="site-heading">
              <h1>Clean Blog</h1>
              <span class="subheading">A Blog Theme by Start Bootstrap</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
          <div class="post-preview">
            <a href="post.html">
              <h2 class="post-title">
                Man must explore, and this is exploration at its greatest
              </h2>
              <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                Problems look mighty small from 150 miles up
              </h3>
            </a>
            <p class="post-meta">Posted by
              <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
              on September 24, 2018</p>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="post-preview">
            <a href="post.html">
              <h2 class="post-title">
                I believe every human has a finite number of heartbeats. I don't intend to waste any of mine.
              </h2>
            </a>
            <p class="post-meta">Posted by
              <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
              on September 18, 2018</p>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="post-preview">
            <a href="post.html">
              <h2 class="post-title">
                Science has not yet mastered prophecy
              </h2>
              <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                We predict too much for the next year and yet far too little for the next ten.
              </h3>
            </a>
            <p class="post-meta">Posted by
              <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
              on August 24, 2018</p>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="post-preview">
            <a href="post.html">
              <h2 class="post-title">
                Failure is not an option
              </h2>
              <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                Many say exploration is part of our destiny, but it’s actually our duty to future generations.
              </h3>
            </a>
            <p class="post-meta">Posted by
              <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
              on July 8, 2018</p>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <!-- Pager -->
          <div class="clearfix">
            <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="#">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <ul class="list-inline text-center">
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <a href="#">
                  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                  </span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <a href="#">
                  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                  </span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <a href="#">
                  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-github fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                  </span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <p class="copyright text-muted">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2018</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
    <script src="js/clean-blog.min.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

I am not sure why but this does not seem to work. The navigation bar is not visible .

Even more strangely when i change the lines :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/font-awesome.min.css') }}"  >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/clean-blog.min.css') }}" >
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='bootstrap.min.css') }}" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='font-awesome.min.css') }}"  >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='clean-blog.min.css') }}" >
```

everything works normally and i can see the indentation and navigation bar works normally . Ideally it should not work since the css files are inside the /static/css folder and not directly under static.

Can someone please tell me what is the issue here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you take a look at the source code of your rendered HTML (in your browser), do the URL looks correct ? Can you access directly the .css in your browser ?

Comment: Yes. Thats even more strange isn't it ? The url is like : /static/bootstrap.min.css . When i click it the css loads up.

Comment: It looks like your static directory is located at `static/css/` instead of `static/`

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43347682/651299

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a problem in your path / folder : Flask seems to be serving files from `static/css/` instead of `static/`.

Try playing with those parameters :

`app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static',static_folder='static/')`

Comment: This is resolved for the timebeing. I cleared the cookies and temporary files and started working as expected. Extremly weird .