# Flask url_for returns 404 (file not found), but the absolute path is correct

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have a `url_for('static', filename='5004648669273537486_0009.mp4')` in my Flask HTML template. But the server returns 404:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2020 17:09:43] "GET /Users/abc/xyz/5004648669273537486_0009.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

In fact, the file `/Users/abc/xyz/5004648669273537486_0009.mp4` really exists. I don't know why Flask cannot find it. The Flask app I declared is as below:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/Users/abc/xyz')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change static folder from config in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346486/change-static-folder-from-config-in-flask)

Comment: Use `static_folder='/Users/abc/xyz'` instead of `static_url_path`. It will work

Comment: Yes. Thanks @tbhaxor! But why? What's the diff? I looked up https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/

Comment: I would rather suggest you to read it again, carefully. You will get it by yourself